# Paypal not working in OJS3.1

Tags: paypal, ojs

[image: Screenshot-1]Recently I have created my e-journal’s website with OJS 3.1 (Fresh installation).

I have configured my Distribution Settings -> Payment -> Paypal Payment Settings
Created a Rest API in Paypal and placed every detail under Account Name, Client ID and Secret. But the paypal payment is not working. Everytime when someone tries to make a purchase it shows a blank screen.

Please help me. I there any problem with the Paypal plugin ? I have also used OJS 2.8 but there was no issues like this and everything was working fine.
[image: Screenshot-2]

Comment: Fixed image links and formatting

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your PHP error log? A blank page typically means something is captured there.

If you see something like...

```
PHP Fatal error: Interface ‘Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface’ not found in /var/www/vhosts/my_domain/httpdocs/plugins/paymethod/paypal/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/RedirectPlugin.php on line 20, referer: http://my_domain/index.php/EI/user/register?source=%2Findex.php%2FEI%2Farticle%2Fview%2F16%2F14
```

...you may be running into https://github.com/pkp/pkp-lib/issues/2996.